# Android ViewModel two way binding is not working

Tags: android, mvvm, data-binding

I am trying to learn how to use MVVM, and two way data binding in Android. I am quite familiar with MVVM and two way data binding from other languages/frameworks (.net, Angular etc)

So, from what I can see, I want a viewModel to retain data, and I also want a **repository**  that I will be passing to a service (eg to play an audio file)

I set up the View model following [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=d7UxPYxgBoA), but i does cover the UI data binding. I'ev looked at a LOT of posts and doco, and there seems to be a lot of different ways of using ViewModel, so is a bit confusing.

In my main activity, I have the following...

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
    initialise()
}

private fun initialise() {
    try {
        val factory = InjectorUtils.provideViewModelFactory()           
        val viewModel = ViewModelProvider(this, factory).get(MainActivityViewModel::class.java)
        viewModel.mode.observe(this, Observer<Int> { mode ->
            // Update
        });
    } catch (ex: Exception) {
        val m = ex.message;            
    }
}
```

and the ViewModel contains

```
package com.example.myApp

import androidx.databinding.Bindable
import androidx.lifecycle.MutableLiveData
import androidx.lifecycle.ViewModel
import com.example.myApp.Modes

// View model to hold all UI state
class MainActivityViewModel(private val repository: Repository): ViewModel() {      
    val mode: MutableLiveData<Int> = MutableLiveData<Int>(0)
    val stopColour: MutableLiveData<String> = MutableLiveData<String>("hello")
    init{
        mode.value = Modes.AUTO_MIDI
        stopColour.value = "123"
    }
}
```

The layout has the variable declared...

```
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
<data>
    <variable
        name="viewModel"
        type="com.example.myapp.MainActivityViewModel" />
</data>
<GridLayout
...
 <RadioButton
    android:textColor="#FCFFFEFE"
    android:id="@+id/radioButtonAuto"
    android:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal"
    android:layout_row="1"
    android:layout_column="0"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@={viewModel.stopColour}"> <--- my test binding
</RadioButton>
```

When I put a break point in the main activity, I can see the ViewModel is created, and has values in it...

[image]

There are no exceptions, however, the bound text ("123") just does not show up in the UI.

What could I be missing here?

Comment: attach the viewmodel with the inflated view and set lifecycler owner in activity

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use DataBindingUtils to bind the view to activity instead of using setContentView.

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

val binding: ActivityMainBinding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(
        this, R.layout.activity_main)
binding.lifecycleOwner = this
binding.viewModel = viewModel [Your viewModel class object]
}
```

basically you need to define the viewLifecycle owner for binding and a value for the variable you created in xml file.
Two way databinding is helpful in cases like EditText. In case of Radio Button or TextView etc you can simply use binding.

```
android:text="@{viewModel.stopColour}"
```

The above code snippet will work fine in case of radio Button.
For more details you can visit android developer documentation link below.
https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding

Comment: Awesome, that is what was missing , and it is now working. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

you need to init your view binding viewModel to Your activity viewModel object
val activityViewModel = ViewModelProvider(this,factory).get(MainActivityViewModel::class.java)

your view binding.viewModel = activityViewModel